# Optimizing email alert code

Tags: c#, optimization, .net, email

To avoid `switch` statements at multiple places, I wrote the following code. This was based on articles found in the Google search. *The object names are not real in the sample below. So please ignore that*.

```
 //somewhere in the code
foreach (IEmailAlertDt alert in EmailAlertFactory.GetEmailAlertDtType(allowedEmails))
{
    if (alert.CheckEmailAlertDt(currReason))
    {                                
         SendEmail(alert.EmailSubject(patRegister.Pat.Id.ToString()), alert.EmailBody(patRegister.Pat.Id.ToString(), patRegister.Organ.Descrip));
         alert.UpdateEmailAlertDt(currReason);
    }
}


[Flags]
enum EmailAlertType
{
    NoAlert=0,
    FirstAlert=1,
    SecondAlert=2,
    ThirdAlert=4
};

static class EmailAlertFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<EmailAlertType, Func<IList<IEmailAlertDt>>> EmailAlertMap = new Dictionary<EmailAlertType, Func<IList<IEmailAlertDt>>>
    {
        {EmailAlertType.FirstAlert,()=> new List<IEmailAlertDt>() {new FisrtEmailAlertDt() } },
        {EmailAlertType.FirstAlert | EmailAlertType.SecondAlert ,()=> new List<IEmailAlertDt>() {new FisrtEmailAlertDt(), new SecondEmailAlertDt() } },
        {EmailAlertType.FirstAlert | EmailAlertType.SecondAlert | EmailAlertType.ThirdAlert,()=> new List<IEmailAlertDt>() {new FisrtEmailAlertDt(), new SecondEmailAlertDt(), new ThirdEmailAlertDt() } }
    };

    public static IList<IEmailAlertDt> GetEmailAlertDtType(EmailAlertType alertType)
    {
        return EmailAlertMap[alertType]();
    }

}


interface IEmailAlertDt
{
    bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason);
    void UpdateEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason);
    string EmailBody(string patID, string Organ);
    string EmailSubject(string patID);
}

class FisrtEmailAlertDt : IEmailAlertDt
{
    public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertFirstDate == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void UpdateEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertFirstDate == null)
            reason.EmailAlertFirstDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public string EmailBody(string patID, string Organ)
    {            
            return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailBody, PatOnHoldSuspension.FIRST_ALERT_DAYS, patID, Organ);             
    }

    public string EmailSubject(string patID)
    {
        return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailSubject, PatOnHoldSuspension.FIRST_ALERT_DAYS,patID);
    }       

}

class SecondEmailAlertDt : IEmailAlertDt
{
    public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertSecondDate == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void UpdateEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertSecondDate == null)
            reason.EmailAlertSecondDate = DateTime.Today;

    }

    public string EmailBody(string patID, string Organ)
    {
        return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailBody, PatOnHoldSuspension.SECOND_ALERT_DAYS, patID, Organ);
    }

    public string EmailSubject(string patID)
    {
        return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailSubject, PatOnHoldSuspension.SECOND_ALERT_DAYS, patID);
    }

}

class ThirdEmailAlertDt : IEmailAlertDt
{
    public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertThirdDate == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void UpdateEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
    {
        if (reason.EmailAlertThirdDate == null)
            reason.EmailAlertThirdDate = DateTime.Today;

    }

    public string EmailBody(string patID, string Organ)
    {
        return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailBody120, PatOnHoldSuspension.THIRD_ALERT_DAYS, patID, Organ);
    }

    public string EmailSubject(string patID)
    {
        return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailSubject120, patID);
    }

}
```

The things that bother me is that there are different small methods like `CheckEmailAlertDt`, with minor difference. In the first `date1` is used and in seconds one `date2` is used. Is there any way I can further optimise/streamline this code?

Comment: Could you explain why are you trying to avoid `switch`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I can ignore names that are as bad as `classDt` or `derclass1`. :-)

Comment: I don't want to combine everything in the `switch` and with our constantly changing requirement it is easy to make mistakes. As I mentioned, in the question, you can ignore names for this question. In the actual App, there are better names used

Comment: @gmailuser  Is it not possible to post the actual code in question?

Comment: I just change the names of objects. The structure is same. Besides that there is a lot of code I've to include here to post actual code.

Comment: @dreza, as requested, I've posted the actual code

Answer (score 1):

1. I really like your use of a `Dictionary` with `Functions`, that is one of my favorite things to do in C# for some reason.
2. Your methods that look like this

   ```
   public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
   {
       if (reason.EmailAlertFirstDate == null)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```

   could be written much simpler as

   ```
   public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
   {
       return reason.EmailAlertFirstDate == null;
   }
   ```
3. Use `switch` Statements.... Or not, if not... this is probably as optimized the code is going to get. Here is my rendition of what your code will look like if using switches instead. I just switched the regular flag enums, although you'll probably want to bitwise OR them with the rest of the values as you were doing in your OP

   ```
   class EmailAlertDt
   {
       public EmailAlertType EmailAlertType { get; private set; }

       public EmailAlertDt(EmailAlertType emailAlertType)
       {
           EmailAlertType = emailAlertType;
       }

       public bool CheckEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
       {
           switch (EmailAlertType)
           {
               case EmailAlertType.FirstAlert: return reason.EmailAlertFirstDate == null;
               case EmailAlertType.SecondAlert: return reason.EmailAlertSecondDate == null;
               case EmailAlertType.ThirdAlert: return reason.EmailAlertThirdDate == null;
               case EmailAlertType.NoAlert: return false;
               default: throw new SomeThingException("My alerts type is all messed up =\\ ");
           }
       }

       public void UpdateEmailAlertDt(PatWaitListStatReason reason)
       {
           switch (EmailAlertType)
           {
               case EmailAlertType.FirstAlert: _updateEmailAlertDt(reason.EmailAlertFirstDate); break;
               case EmailAlertType.SecondAlert: _updateEmailAlertDt(reason.EmailAlertSecondDate); break;
               case EmailAlertType.ThirdAlert: _updateEmailAlertDt(reason.EmailAlertThirdDate); break;
               case EmailAlertType.NoAlert: break;
               default: throw new SomeThingException("My alerts type is all messed up =\\ ");
           }
       }

       private void _updateEmailAlertDt(ref DateTime emailAlertDate)
       {
           if (emailAlertDate == null)
               emailAlertDate = DateTime.Today;
       }

       public string EmailBody(string patID, string Organ)
       {
           object days;

           switch (EmailAlertType)
           {
               case EmailAlertType.FirstAlert: days = PatOnHoldSuspension.FIRST_ALERT_DAYS; break;
               case EmailAlertType.SecondAlert: days = PatOnHoldSuspension.SECOND_ALERT_DAYS; break;
               case EmailAlertType.ThirdAlert: days = PatOnHoldSuspension.THIRD_ALERT_DAYS; break;
               case EmailAlertType.NoAlert: throw new SomeThingException("Halp");
               default: throw new SomeThingException("My alerts type is all messed up =\\ ");
           }
           return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailBody120, days, patID, Organ);
       }

       public string EmailSubject(string patID)
       {
           return String.Format(PatOnHoldSuspension.emailSubject120, patID);
       }
   }
   ```